# Problem with multi tags

Tags: django, url, tagging

If i have url `"/tagged/something/"` then it is good, but if i have `"/tagged/something1-something2/"` it tells me that that page is not found and url didn't matching anything.

urls.py
    `url(r'^tagged/(?P<tags>\w+)/$', 'show_tagged'),`

views.py

```
def show_tagged(request, tags):
    tags = tags.replace(',', '').split('-') 
    items = TaggedItem.objects.get_intersection_by_model(Item, tags)
    return render_to_response('tagged.html', {'items': items}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you try changing your regex? I think the following one will work:  
`url(r'^tagged/(?P<tags>[\w-]+)/$', 'show_tagged'),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing your regex? I think the following one will work:

```
url(r'^tagged/(?P<tags>[\w-]+)/$', 'show_tagged'),
```